# How to capture the names of multiple arguments (...) passed to a function?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidymodels

I have a couple of models that are passed by a function, the number of models is variable. Through (...) I can pass all the models as follows:

```
library(tidymodels)
library(dplyr)

model_1 = decision_tree(mode = "regression") %>%  set_engine("rpart") %>% fit(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = iris)
model_2 = decision_tree(mode = "regression") %>%  set_engine("rpart") %>% fit(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris)

F.function = function(...){
  
  a = list(...)
  a
  
}

F.function(model_1,model_2)
#> [[1]]
#> parsnip model object
#> 
#> Fit time:  15ms 
#> n= 150 
#> 
#> node), split, n, deviance, yval
#>       * denotes terminal node
#> 
#>  1) root 150 102.1683000 5.843333  
#>    2) Petal.Length< 4.25 73  13.1391800 5.179452  
#>      4) Petal.Length< 3.4 53   6.1083020 5.005660 *
#>      5) Petal.Length>=3.4 20   1.1880000 5.640000 *
#>    3) Petal.Length>=4.25 77  26.3527300 6.472727  
#>      6) Petal.Length< 6.05 68  13.4923500 6.326471  
#>       12) Petal.Length< 5.15 43   8.2576740 6.165116 *
#>       13) Petal.Length>=5.15 25   2.1896000 6.604000 *
#>      7) Petal.Length>=6.05 9   0.4155556 7.577778 *
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> parsnip model object
#> 
#> Fit time:  5ms 
#> n= 150 
#> 
#> node), split, n, deviance, yval
#>       * denotes terminal node
#> 
#>  1) root 150 102.1683000 5.843333  
#>    2) Petal.Length< 4.25 73  13.1391800 5.179452  
#>      4) Petal.Length< 3.4 53   6.1083020 5.005660 *
#>      5) Petal.Length>=3.4 20   1.1880000 5.640000 *
#>    3) Petal.Length>=4.25 77  26.3527300 6.472727  
#>      6) Petal.Length< 6.05 68  13.4923500 6.326471  
#>       12) Petal.Length< 5.15 43   8.2576740 6.165116 *
#>       13) Petal.Length>=5.15 25   2.1896000 6.604000 *
#>      7) Petal.Length>=6.05 9   0.4155556 7.577778 *
```

But when the models are saved in the list they do not keep the name, is there any way to have the following output storing the names using (...)?

```
list(model_1 = model_1,
     model_2 = model_2)
#> $model_1
#> parsnip model object
#> 
#> Fit time:  15ms 
#> n= 150 
#> 
#> node), split, n, deviance, yval
#>       * denotes terminal node
#> 
#>  1) root 150 102.1683000 5.843333  
#>    2) Petal.Length< 4.25 73  13.1391800 5.179452  
#>      4) Petal.Length< 3.4 53   6.1083020 5.005660 *
#>      5) Petal.Length>=3.4 20   1.1880000 5.640000 *
#>    3) Petal.Length>=4.25 77  26.3527300 6.472727  
#>      6) Petal.Length< 6.05 68  13.4923500 6.326471  
#>       12) Petal.Length< 5.15 43   8.2576740 6.165116 *
#>       13) Petal.Length>=5.15 25   2.1896000 6.604000 *
#>      7) Petal.Length>=6.05 9   0.4155556 7.577778 *
#> 
#> $model_2
#> parsnip model object
#> 
#> Fit time:  5ms 
#> n= 150 
#> 
#> node), split, n, deviance, yval
#>       * denotes terminal node
#> 
#>  1) root 150 102.1683000 5.843333  
#>    2) Petal.Length< 4.25 73  13.1391800 5.179452  
#>      4) Petal.Length< 3.4 53   6.1083020 5.005660 *
#>      5) Petal.Length>=3.4 20   1.1880000 5.640000 *
#>    3) Petal.Length>=4.25 77  26.3527300 6.472727  
#>      6) Petal.Length< 6.05 68  13.4923500 6.326471  
#>       12) Petal.Length< 5.15 43   8.2576740 6.165116 *
#>       13) Petal.Length>=5.15 25   2.1896000 6.604000 *
#>      7) Petal.Length>=6.05 9   0.4155556 7.577778 *
```

Created on 2021-01-13 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't use any names for those arguments.  If you had, those would have been part of the result.  For example, use

```
F.function(m1 = model_1,m2 = model_2)
```

If you want to generate names from the expressions you pass in, you could do this:

```
exprs <- substitute(list(...))
vals <- list(...)
names(vals) <- vapply(as.list(exprs), deparse, "")[-1]
```

At this point `vals` will contain the arguments passed in `...` with names set to the expressions used to specify them.